# Выделение памяти в Java

Tags: java

Помогите разобраться, что происходит во время выполнения этих строк:

```
1. String str;
2. str = new String("Hi");
```

Во время выполнения первой строки происходит создание ссылки `str` в стеке. А во время выполнения второй выделение памяти в heap и связывание этого участка с ссылкой в стеке. Так?

И как это работает с составними типами? Например:

```
class Temp{
    String str1;
    String str2;
}

1. Temp temp;
2. temp = new Temp();
```

Во время выполнения первой строчки в стеке создастся не только ссылка `temp` но и ссылки `str1`, `str2`

Answer (score 1):

Да, все правильно. Но перед созданием объекта, все его поля должны быть инициализированы. Для этого создается конструктор класса в котором необходимо выделить память в куче, для всех его полей